# Setting Container Height Based on Larger of Two Inner Containers

Tags: html, css

I have a container `div` that has two inner `div`s.  The inner `div`s toggle `display:block/none` on a `hover` over the outer container, so only one inner is visible at any given time.

The outer container has a `min-height`, but can expand depending on the inner contents. If both inner contents are shorter than the `min-height`, everything works well.  However, if one of the  inner containers is taller than the `min-height`, I get a jump in the height of the outer container on hover.

What I want is:

- The outer container keeps its `min-height` if both inner containers are shorter.
- The outer container has the height of the taller of the two inner containers IF either one is taller than the `min-height`
- There is no expanding/collapsing happening on hover at any time.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner inner1">Inner 1 Green</div>
    <div class="inner inner2">Inner 2 Blue</div>
</div>
<div class="after">Some text afterwards</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```
.outer {
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 150px;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px
}

.inner {
    width: 200px;
}

.inner1 {
    background: green;
    height: 200px
}

.inner2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}

.outer:hover .inner1 {
    display: none;
}
.outer:hover .inner2 {
    display: block;
}
```

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/

Important: I am looking for a pure CSS solution.  I could easily fix this with jQuery or basic JS, but this is not an option.

Comment: Do you mind a solution that sets `overflow: hidden` on `.outer`?

Comment: @CarloCannas - Ideally no, but if there is no better solution, I will take it.  Are you thinking about moving the content left and right? :)

Comment: Only left, give a look at my answer.

Comment: @Steve i added an answer.Check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't hide the elements by setting `display` to `none`, instead set their `margin-left` to a large negative number which places them far away the left side of the screen. This way, if you float the two `.inner` and add a clearfix (or better, set `display: hiddden` on `.outer`), the container will always be tall as the tallest child element.

In code:

```
.inner {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.inner1 {
    background: green;
    height: 200px
}

.inner2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -1000px;
}

.outer:hover .inner1 {
    margin-left: -1000px;
}
.outer:hover .inner2 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Then, on the container you have two solutions: the clearfix (http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/3/)

```
.outer:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: left;
}
```

and the *block formatting context* forcing (http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/2/)

```
.outer{
    visible: hidden;
}
```

### Method two

There are also different methods, for example you can hide the unwanted element by shrinking its width to zero. When doing this (with all the floating thing, of course) also set `overflow` to `hidden`, otherwise the content will still be visible. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/4/.

### Without floating

If you don't like the float in there you could try a `inline-block` approach, and set the widths as before. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/5/. This solution needs also a little edit of the HTML code, since if you place a whitespace between the two `.inner` it will be actually rendered (try to remove the comment in the example to see what happens).

Comment: Yes, I fully see what you are doing here.  I was heading this direction too, but was hoping for a slightly cleaner solution.  However, I feel your code is pretty need. :)

Comment: I'll leave the bounty for a little longer, but if there are no other solutions coming in, I would have no problem awarding the bounty to this solution.

Comment: @Steve I included some variants, give a look at them.

Comment: I am now convinced this is the best approach.  Thanks very much for taking the time to understand the exact problem I am facing and putting together a detailed and multi-pronged solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Uses combination of `display` and `visibility` :

**Case 1:** *`.inner1` is always greater than `.inner2`*

```
.inner1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background: green;
    height: 200px
}

.inner2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}
.outer:hover .inner1 {
    visibility:hidden; /*sets visiblity instead of display to maintain height;*/
    width:1px;  /*reduces width to 1px for adjustment."width:0px" will not work. */
}
.outer:hover .inner2 {
    /* Below two lines for .inner2 div to be on same line*/
    display: inline-block; 
    float:left; 
}
```

### <kbd>[See this Demo Fiddle with .inner1 height = 200px](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/12/)</kbd>

Even if you increase the height of `.inner1` the container will adjust the height accordingly:

### <kbd>[See this Demo Fiddle with .inner1 height = 300px](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/13/)</kbd>

---

**OR**

---

**Case 2:** *`.inner2` can be greater than `.inner1`*

### <kbd>[See this Demo Fiddle ***`.inner2 > .inner1`***](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/15/)</kbd>

Change done for above fiddle:

```
.inner2 {
    position:relative;
    right:4px;
    background: blue;
    height: 400px;
    display: none;
}
.outer:hover .inner2 {
    /* Below two lines for .inner2 div to be on same line*/
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Fiddle in response to comment: [Container gets taller div height in the beginning itself](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/18/)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer.  However, Case 1 doesn't do the trick, because it only works when inner1 is taller than inner2.  That is not guaranteed.  Either one can be taller than the other and if you change your fiddle to make inner2 taller, than the solution breaks.  Case 2 doesn't do what I am looking for either, because it expands the outer container on hover.

Comment: I am showing in case two that the container adjusts to the taller div.Case 2 will work for all situations when `.inner1>.inner2` , `.inner1=.inner2` & `.inner2>.inner1`

Comment: Then your fiddle is broken, because in Chrome the outer container's height clearly jumps when hovered.

Comment: I tested it in chrome and case2 fiddle is working correctly.Fiddle of case2 when inner2 is smaller than inner1

Comment: What do you consider correctly?  In http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/15/ when you hover over the container, the outer container becomes taller and adjusts to the height of inner2. That's NOT what I am looking for.  I need a solution where the outer container stays exactly the same height at all times, tall enough to contain inner1 and inner2, no matter which one is taller.

Comment: @Steve check my last fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If the margin trick doesn't work, another option is using `display: table`, then collapse the one not to be shown with a combination of `width: 0` and `visibility: hidden`. The two items will form cells in a row which has the height of the taller one, while the zero width prevents it from otherwise impacting the page layout.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this please ?

Comment: I tried this too (with `display: table-cell`, not `display: table`).  The problem with this approach is that `width: 0` does not actually collapse the cell to 0 width, but to the width of the content.  I could be proven wrong with a fiddle though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe playing with opacity can help
[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audre7/ZhS6c/11/)

all i'v done is

```
.outer:hover .inner1 {
    opacity:0;
}
.outer:hover .inner2 {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
}
```

I put the inner2 in absolute so it goes on top, and so give it a margin top of 10px (cause of the padding of the parent container)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is not exactly what I want, because if inner2 is taller than inner1, this solution breaks.  As I mentioned in the question, the solution needs to work with either inner container being taller than the other.

Answer (score -2):

```
.outer:hover .inner1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Try using `visibility`.

Comment: 'visibility` simply hides the content, but keeps the space of it within the flow.  As a result, I would have a large blank gap where the "hidden" content would be.

Comment: @Steve isn't that what you want? You want the container to keep the height of the largest inner container. This makes it do just that. The outer container keeps the height of the largest inner container, and doesn't change

Comment: I partially want this: However, I don't want both elements to take up space, just the visible one.  If the hidden one is taller, I want it to be completely hidden, but the container keep the height of it (i.e.  the outer is not shrinking to the height of the shorter one).  With `visibility`, both inner containers would take up space, one on top of the other, with the invisible one just having an empty block.

Comment: `There is no expanding/collapsing happening on hover at any time.`: the only way for that to be possible is for the container to keep the height of the largest container. This does that.

Comment: Don't know who -1 this answer. @Steve if you don't want holes then use position to place the elements where you want them. This answer is correct!

Comment: @Markasoftware and tnt - You both might be misunderstanding what I want.  This answer suggests this fiddle as a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/9/ and you will clearly see that this is not an ideal behavior.  The behavior I want is nicely shown in Carlo's example above: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhS6c/2/

Comment: @Steve what if we applied `position:absolute`

Comment: @Markasoftware - `position:absolute` takes the container out of the flow, therefore it is no longer contributing to the height of the outer container.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the min height from the outer and let the hight be determined by the what ever is the highest inner div

```
.outer {
position:relative;
width: 300px;
min-height: 150px;   !!!! remove this 
background: red;
padding: 10px
}
```

Comment: The `min-height` is not preventing the overall height to grow, it just provides a minimum, exactly what I want.

Comment: ignore my answer I didnt read the question properly, give me a min !